# Using np.where with a pandas column. How do you fill the column with the previous value until condition is met again

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this code:

```
df['cross'] = np.where((df['mean_close_spread'].shift(1) < 0) & (df['mean_close_spread'] > 0), 'cross', 'none')

df['cross_price'] = np.where((df['cross'] == 'cross'), df['close'], 'none')
```

The above code gives me the below dataframe

| close | cross | cross_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3434 | none | none |
| 0.3435 | none | none |
| 0.3433 | none | none |
| 0.3434 | cross | 0.3434 |
| 0.3433 | none | none |
| 0.3432 | none | none |
| 0.3431 | cross | 0.3431 |
| 0.4330 | none | none |

Instead of using the "none" string in the cross_price column when there is no cross in the cross column I would like to use the last price from the last cross until the next cross happens.

Here is an example of what i want:

| close | cross | cross_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3434 | none | none |
| 0.3435 | none | none |
| 0.3433 | none | none |
| 0.3434 | cross | 0.3434 |
| 0.3433 | none | 0.3434 |
| 0.3432 | none | 0.3434 |
| 0.3431 | cross | 0.3431 |
| 0.4330 | none | 0.3431 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for `NaN`s if not match `cross`, so possible forward missing values:

```
df['cross_price'] = df['close'].where(df['cross'] == 'cross').ffill() 
print (df)
    close  cross  cross_price
0  0.3434   none          NaN
1  0.3435   none          NaN
2  0.3433   none          NaN
3  0.3434  cross       0.3434
4  0.3433   none       0.3434
5  0.3432   none       0.3434
6  0.3431  cross       0.3431
7  0.4330   none       0.3431
```

Then replacement to `none` not recommended, because get mixed numeric and strings values.

Alternative without `cross` column:

```
m = (df['mean_close_spread'].shift(1) < 0) & (df['mean_close_spread'] > 0)
df['cross_price'] = df['close'].where(m).ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
df['cross'] = np.where((df['mean_close_spread'].shift(1) < 0) & (df['mean_close_spread'] > 0), 'cross', 'none')    
df['cross_price'] = np.where((df['cross'] == 'cross'), df['close'], None) # not 'none'

df['cross_price'] = df['cross_price'].ffill().fillna('none')
```